# Javascript codes work in FF but not in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, prototypejs

The code works fine in Firefox but not in IE. I have done a lots of research, but still couldn't find solution.

This function is called from a button on coldfusion cfc file to allow users manually update a report status. I can exactly get what I want in FF, but it doesn't work in IE.  I added the alert message to debug the problems.  I could get 'Review Status 1', but not 'Review Status 2'.  The error form IE is "The object doesn't support this property or method.".

```
function updateReviewStatus(rowNum) {    
      alert ("Review Status 1");
      var strlen= $("locFund_"+rowNum).innerHTML.split("-")[0].trim().length;
      alert("Review status 2"); 

        $("cerStatus_"+rowNum).update("Review Recommended");
         $("cerStatus_"+rowNum).style.color="green";                    
        $("cerStatus_Bn_"+rowNum).hide();   

        new Ajax.Request("?method=updateUIReviewDB",
            {
            parameters: {   
                     FiscalYear:        $("fyfp_"+rowNum).innerHTML.substr(0,4),
                    FiscalPeriod    :   $("fyfp_"+rowNum).innerHTML.substr(4,2),        
                    PIUniversalID   :   "#JSStringFormat(Arguments.PIUniversalID)#",
                    OPLocCode       :   $("locFund_"+rowNum).innerHTML.split("-")[0].trim().substr(strlen-1,1),
                    OPFund          :   $("locFund_"+rowNum).innerHTML.split("-")[1].trim()
                },
                method: "post"
            }); 

    }
```

Comment: You forgot to describe what exactly is not working. Are there errors in the console? Is the AJAX request made to the server?  Something else?

Comment: "Not working" isn't specific enough.  What does happen?  In particular, what are the parameters set to and what request goes out?

Comment: The construct $("whatever").innerHTML looks really weird.  $(selector) returns a jQuery object, not a HTML element.  I don't think a jQuery object will have innerHTML at all.  I think you mean $("whatever").html().  But then, I don't get your selectors either -- if these are IDs then they should have # in front of them.  Something funky going on here...

Comment: @joelarson I bet that's Prototype and not jQuery (despite the tag).

Comment: Plus, what library are you getting Ajax.Request from?

Comment: @Pointy you are probably right... I'd forgotten about Prototype :)

Comment: You might need to be more specific for Ajax.Request for IE.   `new Ajax.Request("index.php?method=updateUIReviewDB"`

Comment: How to solve prototype issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
var strlen= $("locFund_"+rowNum).innerHTML.split("-")[0].trim().length;
```

IE actually has `trim()` for strings? try

```
var strlen= $("locFund_"+rowNum).innerHTML.split("-")[0].strip().length;
```

Comment: Victor, thank you very much. Your solution is working for FF and IE.